# .htaccess writerule to remove question marks and equal mark

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

today i tried to create .htaccess file that replacing `?` and `=` with `/` ,
test.php code:

```
<?php
echo $_GET['myparam'];
?>
```

.htaccess:

i used this writerule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^test/myparam/([0-9]+)/?$ test.php?myparam=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

ok, i navigated to www.web.com/test.php?myparam=123

**there is no redirect to  www.web.com/test/myparam/123**

so navigated to: www.web.com/test/myparam/123 (Manually) and the php script is worked,

i changed the myparam value to abc instead of 123 : www.web.com/test/myparam/abc

and then it redirects to 404 not found page...(**the server don't know that abc is not directory** `when integer works` `when string 404`)

!**so what i want to do:**!

www.web.com/ test **.php?** inttParam **=** 1 **&** strrParam **=** stringhere **&** p **=** 1

TO

www.web.com/ test/inttParam/1/strrParam/stringhere/p/1

and when i use `$_GET['p']` it will work.

Comment: Of course changing **123** to **abc** won't work -- the rewrite is _only_ matching numbers. Without the URI changed to something "real" (/test.php etc.) it will complain that /test/myparam/abc isn't found.

Comment: You're backwards on this. The _incoming_ URI is `/test/myparam/123` (SEO) and .htaccess is converting it to `/test.php?myparam=123` (dynamic). If you type in the dynamic form, it should be passed unchanged, as it's already in the form needed. If you type in the SEO form, it should be passed to the server/PHP in the dynamic form. By the way, it should be possible to do this generically for multiple terms `/$1.php?$2=$3&$4=$5&...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `i changed the myparam value to abc instead of 123 and it didn't work`

Well of course it won't work since your **rule is matching only numbers in the end**:

```
RewriteRule ^test/myparam/([0-9]+)/?$ test.php?myparam=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

change your rule to this to make it work with anything:

```
RewriteRule ^test/myparam/([^/]+)/?$ test.php?myparam=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

To make it recursion based generic rule to convert `/test/inttParam/1/strrParam/stringhere/p/2` to /test.php?p=2&strrParam=stringhere&inttParam=1`:

```
RewriteRule "^(test)(?:\.php)?/([^/]+)/([^/]*)(/.*)?$" /$1.php$4?$2=$3 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: Great u r :-) anubhava

Comment: I tried this but the css and images are not loading

Comment: You can add this just below `<head>` tag of your page's HTML: `<base href="/" />`

Comment: Thanks it works in my case I had to use `<base href="../../" />`

Comment: `RewriteRule "^(test)(?:\.php)?/([^/]+)/([^/]*)(/.*)?$" /$1.php$4?$2=$3 [NC,L,QSA]`  is not working in my case only `RewriteRule ^test/myparam/([^/]+)/?$ test.php?myparam=$1 [NC,QSA,L]` is working. Can you fix it

Comment: This answer is for a different problem and should not be modified. Please open a new question and I will attend.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on

# do not affect files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\..{2,4})$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?parameter1=$1&%1 [L]
```

Something like that perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

> ok, i navigated to www.web.com/test.php?myparam=123
>   **there is no redirect to www.web.com/test/myparam/123**

I don't know if that means that you also want to make a redirection (presumably 301) from the one with GET params to the one with slashes.

If so, I would recommend to use the previous answer from anubhava and handle any 301 redirection with PHP. Actually, you can redirect with "RewriteRule" using the "R" flag, but I admit that I woundn't know how to solve this particular case.

Anyway, I think there is no need, unless old URLs with GET params were working well at SEO and you didn't wan't to lose ranking.

Comment: "make a redirection (presumably 301) from the one with GET params to the one with slashes." Will everyone _PLEASE_ use the correct terminology? Your incoming URI (from out in the wild) is the SEO (static) form "with slashes", and you are converting it _TO_ the dynamic non-SEO form of a URL Query String ("GET parameters"). Not the other way around. .htacces does NOT see outgoing URLs.

Comment: Sorry about the mess with terminology, but in my answer I was talking about incoming unfriendly URLs, assuming them as permalinks that were to be converted to friendly ones with a 301 redirection.

Comment: Say what? If the incoming (from the "wild") URL is dynamic (non-SEO), you can't use .htaccess to change it to SEO format, because it will come back as SEO and be converted back to dynamic, which will probably cause a loop. Eventually it has to be dynamic (non-SEO) so that the server can find the correct file.